# How to edit ID column to contain specific text in vcf file using awk and sed

Tags: linux, awk, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a vcf file. I need to update the ID column in my vcf file. This is how my vcf file look like:
[image]

0797 NA20798 NA20799 NA20800 NA20801 NA20802 NA20803 NA20804 NA20805 NA20806 NA20807 NA20808 NA20809 NA20810 NA20811 NA20812 NA20813 NA20814 NA20815 NA20816 NA20819 NA20826 NA20828

chr22 16050408 . T C 100 PASS AA=.;AC=134;AF=0.06;AFR_AF=0.1;AMR_AF=0.05;AN=2184;ASN_AF=0.04;AVGPOST=0.9799;DAF_GLOBAL=.;ERATE=0.0046;EUR_AF=0.06;GERP=.;LDAF=0.0649;RSQ=0.8652;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;THETA=0.0149;VT=SNP;ANNOTATION_CLASS=ACTIVE_CHROM;CELL=GM12878;CHROM_STATE=13 GT . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 0|0 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|1 0|1 0|1 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|1 0|1 0|1 0|1 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0

Now I want to update the ID column which is represented as "." by chr22_16050408_T_C_b37 so each ID column in my vcf file should look like chr{no.}_position_refallele_altallele_b37.

I tried to use the following command but its now giving me the answer.

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $1""$2""$3""$4"_b37"}' genotype_chr22_filtered_dosage1.txt
```

This is how the output file should look like:
For ID column:
chr22_16050408_T_C_b37

Comment: `awk 'NR>1 { $3 = sprintf("%s_%s_%s_%s_b37",$1,$2,$4,$5) } 1' infile >outfile`

Comment: @jhnc OP doesn't say that a regular VCF has a header with lines starting with "#"

Answer (score 1):

this is a job for bcftools annotate.

```
bcftools annotate --set-id '%CHROM\_%POS\_%REF\_%ALT'  in.vcf
```

Comment: `...%ALT\_b37' ...` ?

Comment: @jhnc yes, you got the idea... :-)